# React-Bootstrap Alert firing "onClose" immediately upon opening

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Using React, Next.JS and React-Bootstrap

So, i'm trying to just create a dismissable alert, like in the React-Bootstrap documentation, however, it would not close for me. Upon further inspection (that's what the console.logs arefor), i noticed that my Alert component is lauching "onClose" immediately upon being opened. That's a problem. Further more, i've also noticed that no matter what i pass as "onClosing", it reads in the console as "undefined", rather than outputting the function i sent it. This is made further weird, by the fact that just two lines down, im sending the same function, with opposite state to another component (where i signal the website to open the alert), and it's working completely fine. I've been at this for a couple hours now, and i'm pretty stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

My state variable at init

```
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)
```

Here's my Alert component

```
import {Alert, Button, ButtonGroup, ButtonToolbar, Collapse} from 'react-bootstrap'
import PropTypes  from 'prop-types'


const MyAlert = ({onClosing, alertHeading, alertText, alertVariant, methodToExecute, buttonText}) => {
    console.log(onClosing)
    
    return (
        
        <Alert variant={alertVariant} onClose={()=> onClosing} dismissible style={{margin:'1rem'}}>
            <Alert.Heading>{alertHeading}</Alert.Heading>
            <p>{alertText}</p>  
            <ButtonToolbar>
                <ButtonGroup style={{margin:'.5rem .5rem .5rem 0'}}>
                    <Button variant={alertVariant} onClick={()=> {methodToExecute!=undefined ? methodToExecute : onClosing}}>{buttonText}</Button>
                </ButtonGroup>
                <ButtonGroup style={{margin:'.5rem'}}>
                    <Button variant={alertVariant} onClick={() => onClosing}>Close</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
            </ButtonToolbar>
            
        </Alert>
        
    )
}

MyAlert.defaultProps = {
    buttonText: 'OK'
}

/* MyAlert.propTypes = {
    onClosing: PropTypes.func
} */

export default MyAlert
```

And here's my Implementation of it

```
    {showAlert ? <MyAlert onClosing={() => setShowAlert(false), console.log("closing")} alertVariant="danger" alertHeading="Test Alert" alertText="This is just a test alert."/> : ''}
```

The other component implementation i'm sending that setShowAlert to

```
    <ParameterList onRandomList={() => randomListOfInstruments()} onNewList={ () => addNewInstruments()} onClear={() => setShowAlert(true)}></ParameterList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `MyAlert` component is probably the issue here:

```
{showAlert ? <MyAlert onClosing={() => setShowAlert(false), console.log("closing")} alertVariant="danger" alertHeading="Test Alert" alertText="This is just a test alert."/> : ''}
```

You are passing a value to the `onClosing`, `alertHeading`, `alertText`, `alertVariant` props of `MyAlert`, while the actual props of `MyAlert` are:

```
{onClosing, alertHeading, alertText, alertVariant, methodToExecute, buttonText}
```

Among those, you also have `methodToExecute`, which you are using as a condition when loading your alert:

```
<Button variant={alertVariant} onClick={()=> {methodToExecute!=undefined ? methodToExecute : onClosing}}>{buttonText}</Button>
```

Basically, since your `methodToExecute` is always undefined, this button will always activate `onClosing` when clicked.

The solution is to add all the necessary props when using `MyAlert`, or at least include `methodToExecute` function in the props you pass to it, so your button will bind that to the `onClick` function instead.

As for `onClosing` which you are passing as a prop to `MyAlert`, you also need to fix that, because you are calling two functions separated by comma `','` on its implementation:

```
onClosing={() => setShowAlert(false), console.log("closing")}
```

The proper implementation would be:

```
onClosing={() => {
  setShowAlert(false);
  console.log("closing");
}}
```

Comment: Glad to have been of help! :)